# Wick contractions and antisymmetric differential operator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, many-body, greens-functions, wick-theorem

## The problem

I'm trying to rederive Equation S6 in the supplementary of the article PRL 114, 126602 (2015) - ''Spin pumping with spin-orbit coupling''.

The starting point is the imaginary time retarded response function
\begin{equation}
U_i^{\alpha \beta}(r, r'; \tau) = - \langle T_{\tau}\, J_i^{\alpha}(r,\tau)\, S^{\beta}(r',0)\rangle,
\end{equation}
where the spin and spin-current density are
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&J_i^{\alpha}(r,\tau) = \frac{\hbar}{2m_e i}\psi^{\dagger}(r,\tau) \sigma^\alpha \partial^\leftrightarrow_i \psi(r,\tau)\\
&S^{\alpha}(r,\tau) = \psi^{\dagger}(r,\tau) \sigma^\alpha \psi(r,\tau)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
respectively. In this notation $\hbar/2m_e i$ is a constant, $\sigma^{\alpha}$ are Pauli matrices, $\partial^{\leftrightarrow}$ is the antisymmetric differential operator, and $\psi(r,\tau) = (\psi_{\uparrow}(r,\tau),\psi_{\downarrow}(r,\tau))^T$ is the spinor quantum field operator. The angular bracket $\langle \dots \rangle$ denotes an expectation value.

I want to show that, by utilizing Wick's theorem, we can write
\begin{equation}
U_i^{\alpha \beta}(r, r'; \tau) = \frac{\hbar}{2m_e i} \mathrm{Tr}\left\{ \sigma^{\alpha} G(r,r';\tau) \partial_i^{\leftrightarrow} \sigma^{\beta} G(r',r;-\tau)\right\}.\quad(*)
\end{equation}
Here we have defined the Green's function $G(r,r';\tau)_{s_1s_2} = -i \langle T_{\tau}\, \psi_{s_1}(r,\tau)\psi_{s_2}^{\dagger}(r',0) \rangle$, and the trace $\mathrm{Tr}$ is over spin space $s_{1,2,3,4}$.

## The question

My question is related to performing the Wick contractions and the time ordering operator.

By just naively plugging in the expressions for  $J_i^{\alpha}$ and $S^{\alpha}$ I can express the retarded response function as
\begin{equation}
U_i^{\alpha \beta} (r,r';\tau) = - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m_e i} \sum_{s_1 s_2 s_3 s_4} \sigma_{s_1 s_2}^{\alpha} \sigma_{s_3 s_4}^{\beta} \langle T_{\tau} \left(\psi_{s_1}^\dagger (r,\tau) \partial_i^{\leftrightarrow} \psi_{s_2}(r,\tau)\right) \psi^{\dagger}_{s_3}(r',0) \psi_{s_4}(r',0)\rangle.
\end{equation}

By now performing the Wick contractions I should be able to rederive the expression above $(*)$. However, I'm unfamiliar with how to perform the contractions when there is a differential operator acting on one of the terms. In addition, I'm unsure how the authors obtain $-\tau$ in the Green's function. I suspect it is related to that the time ordering must be dealt with explicitly by introducing $\tau^-$ and $0^-$ so that causality is preserved.

To be concise and set the question in a broader perspective:

1. How does one perform Wick contractions in expressions containing derivatives?
2. How should I explicitly deal with the time-ordering symbol in the example given above?